# To recusively go through subfolders within a folder in vbscript?

Tags: recursion, vbscript, filesystemobject

I have written the following subroutine:

```
Sub Openf(fldr,fso,ByRef newf)
  Dim subf,fpath,ext,fname,IsDone
  Set subf=fldr.SubFolders
  If(Not subf Is Nothing) Then
    For Each sf in subf
      fpath=fso.GetAbsolutePathName(sf.Path)
      fname=fso.GetBaseName(fpath)
      If(StrComp(fname,"mm")=0) Then
        IsDone=Delfldr(sf.SubFolders,fso,newf)
      End If
      Openf sf,fso,newf
    Next
  Else
    Set subf=fldr.Files
    For Each sf in subf
      fpath=fso.GetAbsolutePathName(sf.Path)
      ext=CStr(fso.GetExtensionName(fpath))
      If(StrComp(ext,"tar.gz")=0) Then
        Delfile subf,fso,newf
      End If
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

It is supposed to recursively iterate through all the subfolders within a given folder and stop when no more subfolders can be found. At that level, it must get the collection of files that will be present (with the extension `tar.gz`) and then call the `Delfile` subroutine. One more condition is that the subfolders in the `mm` folder must be deleted directly (using `Delfldr` function) without going into them to the level where files can be found.

The problem is that only the folders in the `mm` folders are getting deleted. The script doesn't seem to go through the other subfolders that are present at the same level as the `mm` folder. In other words, the files with the `tar.gz` extension are not getting deleted.

The hierarchy is as follows:

```
C:\backups → c6,mm → es → at01 → files with tar.gz extension
```

Also, is there an equivalent of the `return()` statement in VBScript? I initially thought the problem was because the control wasn't returned back to the calling statement after the `Delfldr` subroutine was executed. So I changed it to a function and returned a bool value to `IsDone`, thinking it will return control to the `Openf` subroutine. However this did not work.

Comment: Please indent your code; it's so unreadable

Comment: Please refrain from making your question less readable than it was before. At least if you expect someone to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues with your procedure:

1. `SubFolders` is always a `Folders` collection, so `sf` will never be `Nothing` and your code will never enter the `Else` branch (thus never processing any files). Change your condition from

   ```
   Not subf Is Nothing
   ```

   to

   ```
   fldr.SubFolders.Count > 0
   ```
2. `GetExtenstionName()` only returns a single extension, so `GetExtensionName("file.tar.gz")` will produce `gz`, not `tar.gz`, so even if your code entered the `Else` branch (which it doesn't) it still wouldn't delete any files. You need something like this to extract double extensions from a file name:

   ```
   ext = fso.GetExtensionName(fso.GetBaseName(fname)) & "." _
           & fso.GetExtensionName(fname)
   ```

   BTW, you don't need `CStr()` here, since `GetExtensionName()` already returns a string.

As for your question regarding `return()`: in what respect to you mean "equivalent"? If you want the procedure/function to return to the caller you can do that via `Exit Sub` and `Exit Function` respectively. If you want to return a value to the caller, you can do that by assigning the value to the function name:

```
Function Foo()
  Foo = "bar"
End Function
```

Note that the latter works only for functions, not procedures. Also, the assignment can take place anywhere in the function body, it doesn't have to be at the end.

On a more general note, I wouldn't use `StrComp()` for string comparisons unless you actually want to make use of the 3-state comparison it does (less/equal/greater). Better (as in "better readable") would be a simple comparison like this:

```
If LCase(ext) = "tar.gz" Then
```